# Return the sheet name when using TextFinder on Google sheets App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am searching for a word in a spreadsheet using TextFinder on Google sheets Script.

I would like to have as an output the name of the sheet where the text was found.

Usually they'll only be 1 of this keyword per spreadsheet and for sure only once per sheet.

If found more than 1 in spreadsheet would be nice to have all sheet names returned.

Code:

```
function TestCMNDH() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  var found = source.createTextFinder('Wordtosearch').matchCase(false).findAll();
  Logger.log(found)
};

Current output: [Range]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get a unique list name of the spreadsheets where the text was found:

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  var foundRange = source.createTextFinder('Wordtosearch').matchCase(false).findAll();

  var sheetNames = foundRange.map(range => range.getSheet().getName());
  var uniqSheetNames = [...new Set(sheetNames)];

  uniqSheetNames.forEach(sheetName => Logger.log(sheetName));
}
```

What you get as a result of the `findAll` function is an array of [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

You can get the Sheet that sheet belongs to using `getSheet()`, and you can get the name of that sheet using `getName()`

So I map that array of `Range` into an array of sheet names:

`var sheetNames = foundRange.map(range => range.getSheet().getName());`

The following line remove any possible duplicate, and then just log the names in the last line